# How can I store currency in MySQL?

Tags: phpmyadmin, decimal, currency

I have csv file i want import to phpmyadmin 5.1 there is currency  number like:

4,292.99 and -106.00

what data type use in phpmyadmin to import this data i try to use DECIMAL (5, 2) and change the number alot without succeeding.
any help?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using Double (10,2) instead